# VSTS Custom Build Number

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Is it possible to set the build number of a VSTS build based off of the result of a PowerShell/Shell script?

I am trying to set it like so currently:

`Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=build.buildnumber;]$VersionNumber"`

However this does not set the build number unfortunately. Having to do this as VSTS doesn't have a way to natively retrieve the latest (or any) git tags from GH!!!

Comment: The documentation [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) suggests `##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]my-new-build-number` should work. It requires the agent version to be 1.88 or higher.

Comment: there's a mod that allows version tagging from the git chechsum of commit (or tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]build number` [logging command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md):

1. Add PowerShell task

Script:

```
 Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]new build number"
```